# Rotation logic in html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas, html5-canvas

I have this animation, but i cant get over the logic. I hope someone can help me here.

Basicly i need this: http://jsfiddle.net/PDE85/9/ but without the arrow doing such crazy moves. It should be attached to the front of the open circle to simulate an expanding arrow.

I got the triangle to [turn right here](http://jsfiddle.net/PDE85/10/) but it doesnt work when i mix it with [position logic](http://jsfiddle.net/PDE85/11/) as seen in the first example.

Here is the code for reference

```
(function() {

    var size = ($(window).height()/5)*4;
    $("#intro-container").css('width',size);
    $("#intro-canvas").css('width',size);
    $("#intro-canvas").css('height',size);

    var interval = window.setInterval(draw, 30);
    var degrees = 0.0;
    var offset = 20;
    var rotate = 0;

    var canvas = document.getElementById('intro-canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    canvas.width = size;
    canvas.height = size;

    draw();

    function draw() {
        if (canvas.getContext) {
            ctx.fillStyle="white";
            ctx.strokeStyle="white";
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, size, size);

            ctx.save();

            ctx.translate(size/2, size/2);
            ctx.rotate(-90 * Math.PI / 180);

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.lineWidth = size/8;
            ctx.arc(0, 0, size/3, 0, rotate * Math.PI / 180);
            //ctx.shadowBlur=1;
            //ctx.shadowColor="black";

            ctx.stroke();

            ctx.restore();

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.save();

            // moving logic
            ctx.translate(size/2, size/2);
            ctx.rotate(-Math.PI / 180 * -rotate+1);
            ctx.translate(-size/3, -size/3);

            // rotating logic
            ctx.translate(size/2, size/2);
            ctx.rotate((rotate * Math.PI + 420) / 180);

            ctx.moveTo(0,0);
            ctx.lineTo(size/6,0);
            ctx.lineTo(0,size/6);
            ctx.lineTo(0,0);

            ctx.fill();


            ctx.restore();

            rotate += 1;

            if(rotate > 360){
                window.clearInterval(interval)
            }

        }
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for this : http://jsfiddle.net/PDE85/12/

The rotation comes from, the rotate call which is unnecessary.

Plus you need an inverted triangle, hence the coordinates needed an update:

```
  ...

  // ctx.rotate((rotate * Math.PI + 420) / 180);
  ctx.moveTo(0,0);
  ctx.lineTo(-size/6,0);
  ctx.lineTo(0,-size/6);

  ...
```

Comment: Ohh so that's what you wanted. Glad that it helped.